# Why do I need to call 'quotes' in this scenario as opposed to using self?

Tags: python, class, reference, attributes

```
class Death(Scene):

     quotes = [
          "You are dead.",
          "Haha. bad.",
          "Sorry, you died.",
          "Probably should try something different."
          ]

     def enter(self):
          print Death.quotes[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
          exit(1)
```

Okay, so I am new to programming and am learning the use of classes by making a text-based game, but I am unsure of why Death.quips is used instead of self.quips, or rather why death.quips is not used instead of self.quips. I think it has something to do with a local reference to quips, but I don't know why you have to use each in the particular circumstances. Thanks!

Comment: `quips` is the same as `quotes` by some typo?

Comment: random.choice selects a random element from a list. If you are importing randint from the random module anyways, using the choice function will make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quotes` is a class variable, not an instance variable. If it were an instance variable, it  would have been set using

```
self.quotes = [...]
```

and would need to be set inside a method that provides the `self` parameter (as seen in your `enter` method)

class variables are accessed using `ClassName.variable`, whereas instance variables from within the class are accessed via `self.variable`.

A good reference for this can be found here: http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/

Comment: Class variables can also be access using self.varname and in fact often should in order to fully support subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by `quips` you meant `quotes` you can actually use either, but they have slightly different affects.

If you use `Death.quotes` this will look inside the class `Death` for an attribute called `quotes` and will use it.

If you use `self.quotes` this will look first inside of your instance `self` and then inside the class of your instance `self` for an attribute called `quotes`. In your particular example this will behave the same as calling `Death.quotes` since `self` is an instance of the class `Death`, but there are some key differences you should note:

1) If your instance variable `self` also had an attribute called `quotes`, then it would be accessed instead of the class attribute by the same name as illustrated by the following example:

```
class Death(Scene):
    quotes = [
        'some awesome quote',
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        sef.quotes = ['foo']

    def some_method(self):
        # This will print out 'some awesome quote'
        print Death.quotes[0]
        # This will print out 'foo'
        print self.quotes[0]
```

2) If `self` is an instance of a subclass of `Death` and that subclass defines it's own class variable name `quotes` then using `self.quotes` would use attribute instead as shown by the following example.

```
class Death(Scene):
    quotes = [
        'some awesome quote',
    ]
    def some_method(self):
        print self.quotes[0]

class DeathChild(Death):
    quotes = [
        'not so awesome quote'
    ]

instance1 = Death()
instance2 = DeathChild()

# This will print out 'some awesome quote'
instance1.some_method()
# This will print out 'not so awesome quote'
instance2.some_method()
```

Now that you understand that, I will tell you that supporting extension through subclassing is actually (usually) a good thing, and I, myself, would use `self.quotes` instead of `Death.quotes`, but it is important to understand why.